# How to change name and price of product in cart via observer in magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2-4-5

How do you change the price and name of a product via Observer in the cart. In Magento 2.4.5 no supermode is available

Answer (score 0):

To change the name and price of a product in the cart via an Observer in Magento 2.4.5, you can create a custom module and define an Observer for the event

**checkout_cart_product_add_after**

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

Create a custom module
Create a new module in **app/code/Vendor/Module** directory with the following files:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php:**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

Create an Observer
Create a new file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ChangeProductPrice.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeProductPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
        $price = 10; // Set the new price here
        $name = 'New Product Name'; // Set the new name here
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $item->setName($name);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

In the above code, you're first getting the cart item from the observer. Then, you're setting the new price and name for the item using setCustomPrice() and setName() methods. Finally, you're saving the changes to the item using the save() method.

Define the Observer in events.xml
Create a new file **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_change_product_price" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeProductPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

n the above code, we're defining the Observer for the checkout_cart_product_add_after event.

Run setup upgrade
Finally, run the following command to upgrade the setup:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now, when a product is added to the cart, the ChangeProductPrice observer will be triggered, and the price and name of the product will be updated according to the code you've defined in the execute() method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It only works with the price. But it does not update the name

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of a product in the cart via an Observer in Magento 2.4.5.you can create a custom module and define an Observer for the event

Create a custom module Create a new module in **app/code/Vendor/Module** directory with the following files:
**Step 1:**
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 2:**
**app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php**:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 3:**
Define the Observer in events.xml Create a new file **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
        <observer name="customname" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomName" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create an Observer Create a new file
**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomName.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomName implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

         /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
         $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
         $item->getProduct()->setName('Custom Name1');
         return $this;
    }
}
```